# Unable to check authentication properly in layouts in NextJS 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJS 14 to setup routing. I am using root layout in `app/layout.js` to check for jwt tokens and conditionally allow page rendering or redirect to /auth/login.
However in doing so, I am getting 2 back-to-back errors.

1. First the app is redirected to /auth/login as expected.
2. Then due to some reason, the `/auth/login` keeps re-rendering multiple times but with the UI of AppLayout.js (tried putting dummy text in AppLayout and figured it out).
3. After a few re-renders, the app crashes, nothing is shown on browser and console gives this error:

```
 ⨯ app/(dashboard)/AppLayout.jsx (10:2) @ Layout
 ⨯ ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at Layout (/home/krush/agro/aggro/.next/server/chunks/_f13a71._.js:137:19)
   8 | export default function Layout({ children }) {
   9 |   const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
> 10 |
     | ^
  11 |   useEffect(() => {
  12 |     if (!token) redirect('/auth/login');
  13 |   }, [token]
```

```js
// app/layout.js

import AppLayout from './\(dashboard\)/AppLayout'
import './globals.css'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className + 'w-full'}>
        <AppLayout>
          {children}
        </AppLayout>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This is the AppLayout where I am trying to conditionally authenticate using jwt tokens. The AppLayout is in a `(dashboard)` group inside NextJS as I only want the layout for the dashboard and not for the auth pages

```js
// app/(dashboard)/AppLayout.js

'use client';

import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) redirect('/auth/login');
  }, [token])

  return (
    <div className='flex-1'>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have no code written yet for auth pages.

```js
// app/auth/login/page.js

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
}
```

As mentioned above, I simply want to use a layout for the whole dashboard(AppLayout) and that layout should not be displayed in /auth/* so have added a group `(dashboard)`. And AppLayout will be using many Client side React functions so I am taking it out of /app/layout.js

The error is definitely exists in the way I have written the token fetching and useeffect code, but I dont know what exactly the error is and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the redirection shouldn't be happening with given route, so that users can access `/auth/login`.
also, don't forget to add route guard for already logged-in users.

the app crashes because memory has just run out; I'd suggest checking redirection often if possible.

```js
// ...
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname
  const pathname = usePathname();
  // check redirection in dev environment, to prevent infinite route loop
  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      console.log('current path:', pathname);
    }
  }, [pathname]);

  // previous code modified
  useEffect(() => {
    // route guard is ignored for '/auth/login'
    if (!token && pathname !== '/auth/login') redirect('/auth/login');
    // and then the same route should be guarded after login
    if (token && pathname === '/auth/login') redirect('/');
  }, [token, pathname])
```

Comment: How do i solve the second part of issue of giving separate layout to auth and separate to the other pages in dashboard group

Comment: @KrushnalPatel try run this code first. I don't really understand what is meant by "re-render". It should not occur unless anything inside JSX is modified. If you're meaning preventing running code of the component, it is essentially not preventable because the component is accessing route data, which is ever-changing in this situation. If preventing running code is absolute necessary, a middleware route guard should be used instead and any route access should be removed from `layout.tsx`.

Comment: This code fixed it. It was not a re-render but a reload altogether. AppLayout also encompasses /auth so each time it reloaded it did not find token, redirected to auth and started the token check again and went into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although you use `use client`, your client component is first rendered on the server. you can test this by adding this `console.log("where am I ");` to your layout file. you will see "where am I " is logged both on the terminal and browser console.. that is why, if you are using `window.localStorage`, you need to make sure you are on the browser environment:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // you should not store token in here.
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // handle redirect logic here
}
```